# Задача из "101 головоломка" про мух SWI PROLOG

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Есть головоломка:

> На оконной занавеске с рисунком в клетку уселись 9 мух. Случайно они расположились так, что никакие две мухи не оказались в одном и том же ряду — ни прямом, ни косом (рис.)
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Задача:
> Спустя несколько минут три мухи сменили места и переползли в соседние, незанятые клетки; остальные 6 не двигались. Но забавно: хотя три мухи перешли на другие места, все 9 снова оказались размещенными так, что никакая пара не находилась в одном прямом или косом ряду. Можете ли вы сказать, какие три мухи и куда пересели?
>
> **Ответ: a6->b6, b3->a4, d4->d3**

Очевидно, что в основе задачи лежит задача о восьми ферзях. В нашем случае она превращается в задачу о 9 мухах. Я реализовал на 9 мух, но с выводом всех возможных расстановок. Мне нужно усовершенствовать эту программу, что бы происходила выбора 3-х мух и проверка их перестановок на соседние клетки и вывод получившегося ответа. Есть ли у Вас какие-то идеи?

---

Добавляю решение, которое я реализовал. Здесь происходит поиск всех ответов, а не на поставленную задачу. Я хотел бы получить ответ только на головоломку, без поиска всех решений. Конкретно это не получается у меня сделать. Я представляю два варианта решения: либо сделать полную реализацию перебора именно 3-ёх мух или отсортировать результаты из которых выбрать именно этих 3-ёх мух и вывести. Можете ли помочь это сделать?

```
myhi([]). % когда список пуст - решение найдено
    
     myhi([ Row/Col | Rest]) :-                   % в противном случае для каждой строки
                myhi(Rest),                       % помещаем муху в каждую высокую строку
                member(Col, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), % и выбираем одну из возможных позиций столбца
                safe( Row/Col, Rest).             % смотрим безопасная ли позиция, если нет, 
                                                  % возвращаемся назад и пробуем  другую
    safe(Anything, []).                           % пустая занавеска всегда безопасная
    
    safe(Row/Col, [Row1/Col1 | Rest]) :-   % проверяем строку
                Col =\= Col1,              % проверяем столбец
                Col1 - Col =\= Row1 - Row, % проверяем диагональ
                Col1 - Col =\= Row - Row1,
                safe(Row/Col, Rest).       % если всё нормально, пробуем подставить
    member(X, [X | Tail]).
    
    member(X, [Head | Tail]) :-
                member(X, Tail).
            
    myhi([1/R9, 2/R8, 3/R7, 4/R6, 5/R5, 6/R4, 7/R3, 8/R2, 9/R1]),write([1/R9, 2/R8, 3/R7, 4/R6, 5/R5, 6/R4, 7/R3, 8/R2, 9/R1]),nl,fail.
```

Comment: Приведите код вашей программы, опишите что конкретно у вас не получается. P.S. И здесь скорее не форум, а база знаний, то есть ваш вопрос и ответы на него должны представлять пользу для других.

Comment: я предоставил ниже своё решение. правильно ли я всё сделал?

Comment: SWI-Prolog имеет встроенный (библиотечный) предикат `member/2`